# Select sum and average from table with different condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table as shown in screenshot

[image: Products table]

I want to fetch the following data in same query

- Sum of all units
- Average of all unit_price only where units > 0

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach (NOTE: I have no access to a PostgreSQL to check syntax, so I'm presenting here a sort of pseudo-code without checking it).

```
SELECT SUM(UNITS)                        AS UNITS_SUM          , 
       SUM(UNIT_PRICE)/POSS_UNITS_COUNT  AS AVERAGE_UNIT_PRICE
  FROM 
   (SELECT UNITS                       AS UNITS              ,
           CASE WHEN UNITS > 0 THEN 1
                ELSE                0
           END                         AS POSS_UNITS_COUNT   ,
           CASE WHEN UNITS > 0 THEN UNIT_PRICE
                ELSE                0
           END                         AS UNIT_PRICE
    FROM Your_Table) A ;
```

Note that this would yield a *DIVIDE BY 0* error if no positive price is in your table (I'm assuming that such condition cannot exist; if it does, you should condition the division using a `CASE` where POSS_UNITS_COUNT must be > 0.

Comment: What would be faster, this or firing two queries to fetch sum and average respectively

Comment: Obviously this one: Here, the table/index is scanned only once while in your case you would cause two consecutive scans. Also, note that the outer SELECT fetches its data from a single-row table (internal SELECT) and hence it should not be considered as a *real* select.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, that uses `filter`:

```
select sum(units),
       avg(unit_price) filter (where units > 0)
from t;
```